# Share intent handler that will post source links from Twitter to Instapaper?

Tags: twitter, instapaper

I'm currently grieving the loss of Twitter-related recipes on IFTTT (ifttt.com).  I used one of the more popular recipes which would go through the Twitter "favorite" tweets and scrape out the first link and send it to my Instapaper account.  It also did the work of following URL-shorteners until it reached the source link and only posted the source link to IFTTT.

I have an Android app that responds to the "Share" intent that I can use from the Twitter app to send links to Instapaper, but it only sends the Twitter.com link and does not scrape the contents of the tweet.

Is there any Android app that implements the "Share" intent that will scrape tweets for me that I share from the Twitter app and post the first embedded link to Instapaper?  I'd take recommendations for other Instapaper-like services but I'd prefer Instapaper if at all possible.

Comment: "Is there an app that does X" questions generally aren't a good fit here. If you can rephrase your question to be more about the problem you're trying to solve it will do better. (There very well may be a non-app solution.)